# Symfony - Get custom param in bundle controller

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, yaml, symfony-3.4

I'm running a website under Symfony 3.4.12 and I created my own custom bundle. I have a custom config file in Yaml :

```
# src/CompanyBundle//Resources/config/config.yml

company_bundle:
    phone_number
```

... and it is launched this way :

```
<?php

# src/CompanyBundle/DependencyInjection/CompanyExtension.php 

namespace CompanyBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;


class CompanyExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('config.yml');
    }
}

?>
```

I would like to retrieve my custom parameters in my controller file, what is the best way to do it ? I tried this way, with no success :

```
$this->getParameter('company_bundle.phone_number')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Read up a bit more on [custom configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/config/definition.html).  You will need a configuration tree and then use $container->setParameter to create the parameters.  Or just define your phone_number as a parameter to start with.  Just like the answer below says though I did beat his post by about 4 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your own `DependencyInjection/Configuration.php`: http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/bundles/configuration.html#processing-the-configs-array

Like that:

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('company_bundle');
    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('phone_number')
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ;
}
```

And then process it into your `DependencyInjection/...Extension.php` file. If you want to make this option as parameter you have to do it like that:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) 
{
     // Some default code
    $container->setParameter('company_bundle.phone_number', $config['phone_number']);
}
```

And then you can get this parameter in your controller like you do.

Comment: It's a little bit too compicated in order to do what I get in my mind. Furthermore, if I have to set every params one by one, it's useless. The idea was to add/edit/remove vars in a yaml file without editing any php file. Many thanks anyway.

Comment: @Paolito75 I suppose you can do it in your `config.yml` inside `parameters` section. But I'm not sure that this will work